# Dropzone.js iOS upload Failure

Tags: javascript, ios, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have run into an interesting problem using Dropzone.js on a project I have been working on.

It works perfectly fine on every browser and device until I reached iOS.  When uploading files in iOS if I pick something from the photo library stored on the device itself using the built-in menu for the photo library the upload fails.

However if I pick a file that is stored on a cloud service from the same exact menu the upload goes through just fine.  It will even let me upload from the device itself if I use an interface other than the standard iOS one by going through a file manager like Readdle Documents.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.  I suspect this is some sort of bug with iOS itself considering that it works just fine if I depart from their interface but I could be missing something.

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Honestly I never did figure out how to repair it, and I haven't retested it with new versions of iOS.  I might have to do some retesting to see if updates have repaired it for us.